# SQL - Como Obter Ultimo Dia do Mês Anterior De Forma Dinamica Nesta Situação

Tags: sql, postgresql

Boas, como é que eu faço para **obter o ultimo dia do mês anterior de forma dinamica(associado a data atual);**

Tenho uma **coluna** que está associada á data em **Milisegundos** **'wo.CREATEDTIME'** - Exemplo de algumas datas nesse formato :

1527807600000

1143564400000

```
SELECT Count(wo.WORKORDERID) AS "Request ID",
CASE 
WHEN cd.CATEGORYNAME =  '01 RMS Application' THEN 'Aplicação'
ELSE cd.CATEGORYNAME 
END AS Category
FROM WorkOrder wo 
LEFT JOIN WorkOrderStates wos 
ON wo.WORKORDERID=wos.WORKORDERID
LEFT JOIN CategoryDefinition cd 
ON wos.CATEGORYID=cd.CATEGORYID
 WHERE  (((wo.CREATEDTIME >= 1527807600000) 
AND ((wo.CREATEDTIME != 0) 
AND (wo.CREATEDTIME IS NOT NULL))) 
**AND ((wo.CREATEDTIME <= 1530399599000)** 
AND (((wo.CREATEDTIME != 0)
AND (wo.CREATEDTIME IS NOT NULL)) 
AND (wo.CREATEDTIME != -1))))  
AND wo.ISPARENT='1' 
AND wo.IS_CATALOG_TEMPLATE='0'
Group By 2
Order By 1 DESC LIMIT 5
```

Na Parte do Where suponho que seja ai que vá ser preciso fazer a condição:
Como faço para dizer que **wo.CREATEDTIME <= "Ultimo dia do mês Anterior**" 
ajuda seria muito bem vinda.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [SQL Coverter/Ober ultimo dia do mes anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313413/sql-coverter-ober-ultimo-dia-do-mes-anterior)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como no seu caso você precisa comparar datas no formato da [`Era UNIX`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix), você precisa obter o **último segundo do mês anterior** e não o último dia como você mencionou na pergunta!

Para se obter a data do último dia do mês anterior em relação ao atual, você pode usar a função [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) combinada com [`now()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), veja só:

```
SELECT (date_trunc('month', now()) - '1 day'::interval);
```

Saída:

```
|             ?column? |
|----------------------|
| 2018-06-30T00:00:00Z |
```

Repare que a saída se refere ao **primeiro momento do dia**, ou seja `00:00:00hrs` do último dia do mês anterior.

Para se obter o **último momento do mês anterior**, você deve subtrair apenas `1 segundo` da data do primeiro dia do mês corrente:

```
SELECT (date_trunc('month', now()) - '1 second'::interval);
```

Saída:

```
|             ?column? |
|----------------------|
| 2018-06-30T23:59:59Z |
```

Agora sim podemos usar a função [`date_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) para se extrair a [`Era UNIX`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix) do `TIMESTAMP` calculado:

```
SELECT
    date_part( 'epoch', ( date_trunc('month', now()) - '1 SECOND'::INTERVAL) );
```

Saída:

```
|  date_part |
|------------|
| 1530403199 |
```

Como no seu caso, você precisa da [`Era UNIX`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix) calculada em **milissegundos**, basta multiplicar tudo por `1000`, *voìla*:

```
SELECT
    date_part( 'epoch', ( date_trunc('month', now()) - '1 SECOND'::INTERVAL) ) * 1000;
```

Saída:

```
|      ?column? |
|---------------|
| 1530403199000 |
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/17513)

Comment: Como o que ele deseja é wo.CREATEDTIME <= "Ultimo dia do mês Anterior" seria mais simples fazer wo.CREATEDTIME < "Início do primeiro dia do mês atual".

Answer (score 3):

O PostgreSQL tem varias funções para manipular datas. Primeiro, com [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), você trunca a data para ter o ano e o mês atual. Da documentacao:

> field selects to which precision to truncate the input value. The return value is of type timestamp or interval with all fields that are less significant than the selected one set to zero (or one, for day and month).

OU seja, você passa o campo que você quer truncar ('year', 'month,'hour', etc.) e ele retorna pra você uma data com os valores menos significantes zerados. Com isso você consegue ter o primeiro dia do mês atual.

Mas você quer o dia anterior ao primeiro dia do mês. Para isso, basta subtrair 1 dia da data truncada. Essa subtração você consegue fazer com o comando [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html), bastando passar o intervalo de 1 dia.

Fica então assim a consulta:

```
postgres=# select (date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 day');
    ?column?
------------------------
 2018-06-30 00:00:00-04
(1 row)
```

Mas a data ainda está em formato de data, não de milissegundos. Para transformar você deve usar a função [date_part](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html), responsável por extrair informações de datas.

```
postgres=# select date_part('epoch', date_trunc('month', now()));
   ?column?
---------------
 1530417600
(1 row)
```

Retornando o tempo em segundos. Para milissegundos, basta multiplicar por 1000;

Sua consulta com o WHERE ficaria algo do tipo (versão simplificada):

```
SELECT Count(wo.WORKORDERID) AS "Request ID",
...
FROM WorkOrder wo
...
WHERE wo.CREATEDTIME <= date_part('epoch', date_trunc('month', now())) * 1000;
```

Comment: Testei agora assim por alto e parece que está funcionado obrigado , ótima explicação

Comment: As datas são comparadas no formato da `Era UNIX`, você precisa obter o último **segundo** do mês anterior e não o último dia! Isso causa um erro de `86400000` milissegundos. Veja a minha resposta.

Comment: Veja só: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/17515